# How to parse lua file in android?

Tags: android, parsing, lua

I have .lua file I want to parse in my android applicatio. The data in the lua file looks like this

```
[animals = {  
    {"Ball Python"} = {
        latin="Python Regius", 
        coneAmount="2",
        b1 = 0.002986990142123, 
        b2 = -0.00041641579599036, 
        b3 = 0.018301765421868, 
        rg1 = 0.032178276140867, 
        rg2 = 0.090048596751619, 
        rg3 = 0.011366901541786, 
        b4 = 5.32244664084025, 
        rg4 = 34.0664124807393, 
        algo_type = 1, 
        circle_image_name = "Ball_Python.png",
    }, {"Bat - Pallas's Long-Tongued"} = {
        latin="Glossophaga Soricina", 
        coneAmount="2",
        ...
    }, {"Bear - Polar"} = {
        ...
    ,}, ...
 }]
```

How can I parse the file. Please give some solutions, thanks

Comment: Please clarify question. Now it's an unreadable one-long-sentence hell.

Comment: lua is a programming language, no data structure like json or xml.

Comment: i have got animals.lua file from someone but i ma unbale to parse this file if you gave any sugestion then please give me solutions thanks

Comment: How exactly do you want to parse? It's true that this is some data, but it's also a valid piece of Lua code, it's best to use Lua to get data.

Comment: This is not valid Lua.

Answer (score 1):

First. Use dots. Seriously. They are awesome!

Second. Your lua file is invalid. It will not even compile. `[]` can be used for table access, 
or inside declaration, `{["I'm the answer"] = 42}`

Third. To parse Lua use Lua. [Scripting Layer for Android (SL4A)](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) gives you a fast and easy way to communicate with Lua.

Comment: can you post the code to parse this file

Comment: @user3247237 See point 2. It won't ever compile. http://codepad.org/21C3oIKk

Comment: animals = {
    ["Ball Python"]                 ={latin="Python Regius"                  , coneAmount="2" ,b1= 0.002986990142123   , b2=-0.00041641579599036 , b3= 0.018301765421868   , rg1= 0.032178276140867   , rg2= 0.090048596751619   , rg3= 0.011366901541786   , b4= 5.32244664084025    , rg4= 34.0664124807393    , algo_type=1, circle_image_name="Ball_Python.png",}}

Comment: please compile this structure

Comment: how to compile the file can you tell me? is there any online compiler